# parsing first and last names from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, parsing

I have a column in my SQL Server 2008 database that contains `c/o Full Name`. I'm having issues getting the First and Last names separated. I have the c/o in its own column, but I need the First/Last Names. I know that there is an issue with the second and third case statement, but I'm not sure what I need to change. Should I be storing index variables somewhere to reference them?

```
Declare @t table ( [name] varchar(100) )

INSERT INTO @t ( Name )
SELECT Street1 FROM tblPeople
WHERE CO = 'Y' AND LastName NOT LIKE 'SUMMERHAVEN INC' AND Street1 Like '%c/o%'

SELECT
    [name],
    CHARINDEX(' ', [name]),
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [name]) > 0 THEN
        LEFT([name],CHARINDEX(' ',[name])-1)
    ELSE
        [name]
    END as CO,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [name]) > 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING([name],CHARINDEX(' ',[name])+1, ( LEN([name]) - CHARINDEX(' ',[name])+1) )
    ELSE
        NULL
    END as FIRST_NAME,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [name]) > 0 THEN
        SUBSTRING([name],CHARINDEX(' ',[name])+1, ( LEN([name]) - CHARINDEX(' ',[name])+1) )
    ELSE
        NULL
    END as LAST_NAME
FROM @t
```

Comment: Looks like SQL Server? Which version?

Comment: @HartCO I added the version in the quesiton, but it is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: How about some sample data? We don't have your table tblPeople.

Comment: @SeanLange an example of a name would be `c/o Sara Schultz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure: this is a bad idea to parse the data like this, but here you go:

```
Declare @t table ( [name] varchar(100) )

insert into @t ( Name ) values ('c/o Full Name')

SELECT
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [name]) > 0 THEN
    LEFT([name],CHARINDEX(' ',[name])-1)
ELSE
    [name]
END as CO,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [name]) > 0 THEN
    SUBSTRING([name],CHARINDEX(' ',[name])+1, CHARINDEX(' ',[name]) )
ELSE
    NULL
END as FIRST_NAME,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [name]) > 0 THEN
    SUBSTRING([name],CHARINDEX(' ',[name], CHARINDEX(' ',[name])+1), len([name]))
ELSE
    NULL
END as LAST_NAME
FROM @t
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is a bad idea to parse data like this?

Comment: @kevorski because this is not a reliable way to parse the data. What if you have multiple first names? Or a complex last name where users would leave a space? Of course, if you get this data from a source that you cannot change then you stuck with what you have and it is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

To my surprise, [PARSENAME()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) was available in 2008

Consider the following

```
Declare @YourTable table (Name varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
 ('c/o Cher')
,('c/o John Smith')
,('John Smith')

Select *
      ,FirstName=parsename(replace(ltrim(rtrim(replace(name,'c/o',''))),' ','.'),2)
      ,LastName =parsename(replace(ltrim(rtrim(replace(name,'c/o',''))),' ','.'),1)
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Name            FirstName   LastName
c/o Cher        NULL        Cher
c/o John Smith  John        Smith
John Smith      John        Smith
```

Comment: @SeanLange I believe you are the one who informed me of this some time ago.  Curious docs show 2012+

Comment: Yeah the documentation is a bit bizarre. Things like "show other versions" and it only goes back to 2012 but other items it will go back further. And then of them like you say will mention that is only available in 2012+ which is just wrong. Not sure why they have gone this route.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using Common Table Expressions which so that the logic for finding the spaces to break on is reasonably self-documenting.

```
Declare @t table ( [name] varchar(100) )

insert into @t ( Name )
select 'one two three'
union select 'a bc def'
union select 'one two'
union select 'one'

;with cte1 as 
(
    select name
    ,charindex(' ', name) FirstSpace
    from @t
)
, cte2 as (
    select name
    , FirstSpace
    ,charindex(' ', name, FirstSpace+1) SecondSpace
    from cte1
)
select name
, FirstSpace
, SecondSpace
, case when FirstSpace=0 then name else substring(name, 1, FirstSpace-1) end Company
, case when SecondSpace=0 then null else substring(name, FirstSpace+1, SecondSpace-FirstSpace-1) end FirstName
, case when SecondSpace=0 or SecondSpace=len(name) then null else substring(name, SecondSpace+1, len(name)-SecondSpace) end LastName
from cte2
```